# I am receiving a SIGSEGV error on the following code (pointers) and don't know where I am going wrong

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Here is the code I am building (with an explanation of my assignment):

```
/*
  Proposal:
    Create a list-based graph representation.

    It will need to support the following operations.
      1. Ask the user how many Vertices there are.

      2. Ask the user to label those Vertices, ie "A", "B", "C"...

      3. Define the graph as an array of linked lists based on the number of
      Vertices that hold labels. The node type would support the label and weight.

      4. Repeatedly ask the user to define edges between two Vertices with the weight of the edge. Add these edges to the list.

      5. Have a list method that will list out all of the edges in the graph
      with their weights.

  Sample Run:
  N/A
*/
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>


// ========== Struct Definition(s) ==========
struct AdjListNode {
  int dest;
  std::string label;
  int weight;

  struct AdjListNode* next;
};


struct AdjList {
  struct AdjListNode *head;
};


// ===== Class Definition(s) ==========
class Graph {
  private:

    int num;
    struct AdjList* array;

  public:
    std::string *a;

    Graph(int);

    void addEdge(int, int, int, std::string, std::string);
    void label(std::string,int);
    void output();

    AdjListNode* newAdjListNode(int point, int weight, std::string labelname) {
      AdjListNode* newNode = new AdjListNode;

      newNode->dest = point;
      newNode->weight = weight;
      newNode->label = labelname;
      newNode->next = NULL;

      return newNode;
    }
};


// ========== Function Prototype(s) ==========
// In Class(es)


// ========== Main Function ==========
int main() {
  int num, distance, choice, head, tail;
  std::string input;

  std::cout << "Enter the number of vertices: ";
  std::cin >> num;

  Graph graph(num);

  std::cout << "\nPlease label the vertices ('A', 'B', 'C', etc.)\n";

  for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    std::cout << "Label for vertex " << (i+1) << ": ";
    std::cin >> input;

    graph.label(input, i);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    std::cout << "\nEnter two edges between " << "OUTPUT i and i+1 vertices (e.g. 1 5): ";
    std::cin >> head >> tail;

    std::cout << "Enter the weight of this edge: ";
    std::cin >> distance;

    graph.addEdge(head, tail, distance, graph.a[head], graph.a[tail]);
  }

  graph.output();

  return 0;
}


// ========== Function Definition(s) ==========
Graph::Graph(int num) {
  this->num = num;

  array = new AdjList [num];
  a = new std::string [num];

  for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
    array[i].head = NULL;
  }
}


void Graph::addEdge(int a, int b, int weight, std::string bname, std::string tname) {
  if( a >= num || b >= num || a < 0 || b < 0) {
    std::cout << " Input is invalid\n";
  }

  else {
    AdjListNode* newNode = newAdjListNode(b,weight, tname);

    newNode->next = array[a].head;
    array[a].head = newNode;
    
    newNode = newAdjListNode(a,weight, bname);
    newNode->next = array[b].head;
    array[b].head = newNode;
  }
}


void Graph::label(std::string b, int i) {
  a[i] = b;
}


void Graph::output() {
  std::string input;

  for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    AdjListNode* list = array[i].head;
    std::cout << "\nAdjacency list of the vertex " << i << " with labeled name: " << a[i];

    while (list) {
      std::cout << list->dest << " with the labeled name " << list->label << " and the weight being " << list->weight << "\n";
      list = list->next;
    }

    std::cout << "\n";
  }
}
```

I am receiving the error when hitting this line: `graph.addEdge(head, tail, distance, graph.a[head], graph.a[tail]);`, however, I suspect the issue lies within my class definition and how it is setup.

Can anyone offer me some assistance here?

I am running the code [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler) (onlinegdb)

What is stopping me is that I *slightly* understand what the **SIGSEGV** error is, but I just cannot see where I am incorrectly trying to access memory. The debugger is showing `graph` has the following -> `{num = 2, array = 0x614c20, a = 0x614c48}`, but those points in memory should be accessible since I am *reserving* them, no?

Clarification for the `graph` values - I am entering **2** vertices and for the first *2 edges*, I am entering `1` and `5` with a weight of `5`

Here is the exact I/O of the program when I run it:

```
Enter the number of vertices: 2                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                    
Please label the vertices ('A', 'B', 'C', etc.)                                                                                                                     
Label for vertex 1: A                                                                                                                                               
Label for vertex 2: B                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                    
Enter two edges between OUTPUT i and i+1 vertices (e.g. 1 5): 1 5                                                                                                   
Enter the weight of this edge: 2                                                                                                                                    
Segmentation fault (core dumped)                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                    
...Program finished with exit code 139                                                                                                                              
Press ENTER to exit console.
```

Comment: Please provide the exact input. It's even better to provide hardcoded values.

Comment: Great suggestion, @jabaa - I have updated the question at the bottom with the I/O

Comment: What's wrong with this input: https://wandbox.org/permlink/PyzdA8jJLSXX5l1K

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to wandbox @jabaa , that looks like a very helpful resource. Have you tried running it in the provided compiler (onlinegdb)? I am not sure why wandbox runs as intended and onlinegdb fails... I am starting to think there is an issue with onlinegdb rather than my code

Comment: _"I am starting to think there is an issue with onlinegdb rather than my code"_ You can be sure it's a problem with your code. It's probably undefined behavior somewhere in your code (reading/writing out of bounds, reading uninitialized values, ...)

Comment: @jabaa - so let's say that is the case (issue with the code), and I'm sure you are correct, can you help me *find* the problem? I am still not understanding why it is working in wandbox and not onlinegdb.

Comment: You're setting `tail` to `5` and in `Graph::addEdge` you have `array[b].head;` with `array[5].head;` but `array` has two elements. `array[5]` is an out of bounds access. You should use a `std::vector` instead and `std::vector::at` instead of `operator[]` to find these problems.

Comment: You have a memory leak. Your code should contain one `delete` for each `new`. Use STL containers to avoid such leaks.

Comment: @PythonReactor `std::string *a;` -- Why is this a pointer?  Why not simply `std::vector<std::string> a;`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - jabaa pointed me in the right direction with vectors and you are both correct. It definitely made life much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`graph.a` has two elements but `tail` is set to `5` and `graph.a[tail]` is an out of bounds access. It causes undefined behavior.

You should avoid dynamic memory allocation and use `std::vector` instead. `std::vector` provides `std::vector::at` to help finding these bugs. You pay for it with performance. `std::vector::at` adds range checks and is a little bit slower but searching for bugs makes you slower.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct AdjListNode {
  int dest;
  std::string label;
  int weight;

  AdjListNode* next;
};

struct AdjList {
  AdjListNode *head;
};

class Graph {
  private:

    int num;
    std::vector<AdjList> array;

  public:
    std::vector<std::string> a;

    Graph(int);

    void addEdge(int, int, int, std::string, std::string);
    void label(std::string,int);
    void output();

    AdjListNode* newAdjListNode(int point, int weight, std::string labelname) {
      AdjListNode* newNode = new AdjListNode;

      newNode->dest = point;
      newNode->weight = weight;
      newNode->label = labelname;
      newNode->next = nullptr;

      return newNode;
    }
};

int main() {
  int num, distance, head, tail;
  std::string input;

  std::cout << "Enter the number of vertices: ";
  std::cin >> num;

  Graph graph(num);

  std::cout << "\nPlease label the vertices ('A', 'B', 'C', etc.)\n";

  for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    std::cout << "Label for vertex " << (i+1) << ": ";
    std::cin >> input;

    graph.label(input, i);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    std::cout << "\nEnter two edges between " << "OUTPUT i and i+1 vertices (e.g. 1 5): ";
    std::cin >> head >> tail;

    std::cout << "Enter the weight of this edge: ";
    std::cin >> distance;

    graph.addEdge(head, tail, distance, graph.a.at(head), graph.a.at(tail));
  }

  graph.output();

  return 0;
}

Graph::Graph(int num) : array(num), a(num) {
  this->num = num;

  for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
    array.at(i).head = nullptr;
  }
}

void Graph::addEdge(int a, int b, int weight, std::string bname, std::string tname) {
  if( a >= num || b >= num || a < 0 || b < 0) {
    std::cout << " Input is invalid\n";
  } else {
    AdjListNode* newNode = newAdjListNode(b,weight, tname);

    newNode->next = array.at(a).head;
    array.at(a).head = newNode;
    
    newNode = newAdjListNode(a,weight, bname);
    newNode->next = array.at(b).head;
    array.at(b).head = newNode;
  }
}

void Graph::label(std::string b, int i) {
  a.at(i) = b;
}

void Graph::output() {
  std::string input;

  for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    AdjListNode* list = array.at(i).head;
    std::cout << "\nAdjacency list of the vertex " << i << " with labeled name: " << a.at(i);

    while (list) {
      std::cout << list->dest << " with the labeled name " << list->label << " and the weight being " << list->weight << "\n";
      list = list->next;
    }

    std::cout << "\n";
  }
}
```

An exception is thrown:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 5) >= this->size() (which is 2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel like a fool - I realize this was less of an understanding of graphs, rather than an issue with the code (kinda). I now see what you were saying in trying to set the tail to an index that is beyond the available number of vertices.

This was *very* helpful in many ways.